# Logback config is ignoring my logging level

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm getting ecessive logging in my project, and I'm having trouble supressing the logging statements I don't want.

I'm using Logback which I installed by adding to my POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

My logs always start with these three lines:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Googling indicates this is Eclipse issue and not a Logback configuration issue, but I'm including it in case my Googling mislead me.

Here is my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.my.project" level="TRACE"/>
  <logger name="o.a.cxf" level="INFO"/>
  <logger name="o.a.c" level="INFO"/>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

And here's an excerpt from my logs

```
[INFO] 17:41:53.095 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.095 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.095 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.096 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.096 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.096 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.096 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA cipher suite is excluded by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.097 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.103 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.103 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.103 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.104 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.104 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.104 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA cipher suite is included by the filter.
[INFO] 17:41:53.104 DEBUG o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory - The TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 cipher suite is included by the filter.
```

I've verified that my logback.xml file is being read by modifying the pattern in the appender. Those changes are being respected. But I expected setting the logger for "o.a.c" to INFO would suppress these DEBUG messages. I'm assuming the [INFO] is also coming from Eclipse, and the DEBUG later in the line is the actual logger level.

### Update

These loggers are logged by Apache CXF. There is a dependency in my project that has stub-code generated with CXF. When I use that stub code to invoke the webservice these loggers are generated. I didn't write these logging statements, so I can only assume they are coming from CXF.

Also, I don't see these loggers when I use Log4j. I'm trying to learn Logback as I've been assigned to evaluate it as a possible upgrade for the team.

Comment: Logging when/where? How are you launching your project? Most notably, this is a well-known m2e problem that shows up most often with JUnit, and it's scheduled for a fix in Luna.

Comment: I've updated the question to include that information. However, if the XML config file is setup correctly, does it really matter where/how the logging statements are created? I'm under the impression that if I set the logging level for a logger it should be suppressed regardless of where it's called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it is showing `o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory` in the log message, the logger name is in fact not `o.a.c.t.h.HttpsURLConnectionFactory`.  `o.a.c...` is simply an abbreviation of the full name.

I think you should use `org.apache.cxf` instead of `o.a.c` and `o.a.cxf` in your `logback.xml`

Comment: That did it! We've got some large complex projects and I might not know what's causing the loggers. Do you know of any way to turn off the abbreviation?

Comment: In your pattern, you are using `%logger{36}`.  Just use `%logger` instead